# Stokes theorem integral, normal vector confusion

Tags: vectors

**Here's the question**. I was told I should be using Stokes theorem.

[image]

**Here's my Work:**

$\operatorname{curl} F \cdot dS$:

$$(\nabla \times F) \cdot N \, dS=(2xz^2 \hat {y}, -2 \hat{z})\cdot(18y \hat {y}, 1 \hat{z})\,dxdy$$

As for the limits, for the answer of 4 I did -1 to 1 wrt y, and -3sqrt(1-y^2) to 3sqrt(1-y^2).

For -24 I did -1 to 1, and -3 to 3, for dy and dx, respectively. Clarified below:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-3\sqrt1-y^2}^{3\sqrt1-y^2}\,dx\,dy$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-3}^{3}\,dx\,dy$$

**Extra:**

I've been trying to get the correct answer to this problem for a while now, and I just can't seem to get it. I've looked at numerous sources for help, and most of the time I understand, but sometimes I simply do not, although at times it may be due to the source itself.

I've tried to do the question 2 different ways: One way I do it I get an answer of 4, and another way, an answer of -24, both of which I believe is incorrect because the professor has told me the answer is 6 (I remember 6, might have been 6pi, but I do remember the number 6).

The explanation and theory of Stokes theorem I understand, at least I believe I do. But there's times when I simply do not understand why the normal vector is what it is. I understand for a scalar field you do the absolute, and for a vector field you do not, but what about for Stokes? I see 2 or 3 different ways people do it, and I am confused as to how I should be doing it here. I believe that is my problem in this case, although it could be the limits itself.

**Extra extra:**

Again, sorry for my lack of proper formatting. I googled how to make nice formulas in stackexchange but I couldn't get a straight answer. Also, you may be asking me, why do I not convert to cylindrical coordinates? The answer is: Because I am lost. If the area over integration was a cylinder of uniform radius, I probably would have done that, but I am just confused with so many dynamics of this theorem.

**Assumptions:**

$z\ge0$, outwards normal vector (Confirmed with prof)

Comment: This question does not make sense, as it stands. The surface goes on forever and the integral does not have a limit. In order to apply Stokes's Theorem, you would need to cut the surface off, say by saying $z\ge 0$, so that it will have a boundary curve. There's the additional problem that the orientation on the surface is not given. You had better ask your professor what the problem *should* say.

Comment: For formatting see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Thanks, I just emailed my professor about this. It is due tomorrow, and he says he doesn't take questions over email. I might just have to make that assumption that yes, its $z≥0$ and its orientation is upwards.

Comment: For my final submission I converted to polar and my final answer was -6pi. Not sure if I'm correct, figured I'd follow up.